# Finding maximum of $|z|$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\left|z+\frac{1}{z}\right|=4$ then find the maximum value of $|z|$.

Is there an algorithm to find the maximum value in general?

Comment: Use http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumberInequalities.shtml

Comment: joukowski function maybe helpful

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, you want $z$ and $\frac1z$ pointing in opposite directions. So you would want to use $|z+\frac1z| + |-\frac1z| \ge |z|$, which gives $|z| - \frac1{|z|} \le 4$, which you should be able to solve via the corresponding quadratic equation. You then need to check that the bound you get for $|z|$ is attainable, which should of course be at the equality case.